# Finding number of inserted documents in a bulk insert with duplicate keys

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, tornado-motor

I'm doing a bulk-insert into a mongodb database. I know that 99% of the records inserted will fail because of a duplicate key error. I would like to print after the insert how many new records were inserted into the database. All this is being done in python through the tornado motor mongodb driver, but probably this doesn't matter much.

```
try:
    bulk_write_result = yield db.collections.probe.insert(dataarray, continue_on_error=True)
    nr_inserts = bulk_write_result["nInserted"]
except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError as e:
    nr_inserts = ????  <--- what should I put here?
```

Since an exception was thrown, `bulk_write_result` is empty. Obviously I can (except for concurrency issues) do a count of the full collection before and after the insert, but I don't like the extra roundtrips to the database for just a line in the logfile. So is there any way I can discover how many records were actually inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular insert with continue_on_error can't report the info you want. If you're on MongoDB 2.6 or later, however, we have a high-performance solution with good error reporting. Here's a complete example using Motor's BulkOperationBuilder:

```
import pymongo.errors
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from motor import MotorClient

db = MotorClient()
dataarray = [{'_id': 0},
             {'_id': 0},  # Duplicate.
             {'_id': 1}]


@gen.coroutine
def my_insert():
    try:
        bulk = db.collections.probe.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()

        # Prepare the operation on the client.
        for doc in dataarray:
            bulk.insert(doc)

        # Send to the server all at once.
        bulk_write_result = yield bulk.execute()
        nr_inserts = bulk_write_result["nInserted"]
    except pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError as e:
        print(e)
        nr_inserts = e.details['nInserted']

    print('nr_inserts: %d' % nr_inserts)


IOLoop.instance().run_sync(my_insert)
```

Full documentation: http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/examples/bulk.html

Heed the warning about poor bulk insert performance on MongoDB before 2.6! It'll still work but requires a separate round-trip per document. In 2.6+, the driver sends the whole operation to the server in one round trip, and the server reports back how many succeeded and how many failed.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! As a small addition, the try/except only needs to be around the `bulk.execute()`, and I added `if not all(map(lambda we: we["code"] == 11000, e.details["writeErrors"])): raise` to the exception handler, to check if all errors are indeed duplicate keys

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear to me why you `yield` your insert result. But, concerning the [bulk inserts](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html#unordered-bulk-write-operations):

- you should use [`insert_many`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) as [`insert`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert) is deprecated;
- when setting the `ordered` keyword to `False`, your inserts will continue in case of error;
- in case of error, `insert_many` will raise a [`BulkWriteError`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html#pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError), that you can query to obtain the number of inserted documents.

All of this lead to something like that:

```
try:
  insert_many_result = db.collections.probe.insert_many(dataaray,ordered=False)
  nr_inserts = len(insert_many_result.inserted_ids)
except pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError as bwe:
  nr_inserts = bwe.details["nInserted"]
```

---

If you need to identify the *reason* behind the write error, you will have to examine the `bwe.details['writeErrors']` array. A code value of 11000 means "Duplicate key error":

```
>>> pprint(e.details['writeErrors'])
[{'code': 11000,
  'errmsg': 'E11000 duplicate key error index: test.w.$k_1 dup key: { : 1 }',
  'index': 0,
  'op': {'_id': ObjectId('555465cacf96c51208587eac'), 'k': 1}},
 {'code': 11000,
  'errmsg': 'E11000 duplicate key error index: test.w.$k_1 dup key: { : 3 }',
  'index': 1,
  'op': {'_id': ObjectId('555465cacf96c51208587ead'), 'k': 3}}
```

Here, as you can see, I tried to insert two documents in the `w` collection of the `test` db. Both inserts failed because of a duplicate key error.

Comment: The `yield` is an artefact of using the asynchronous tornado mongodb `tornado-motor` driver. This non-blocking driver attempts to be compatible with pymongo, but indeed I see that `insert_many` is not available in `tornado-motor`. Still useful information though!

Comment: I haven't updated Motor to the new MongoDB Driver CRUD API, so Motor's API still matches PyMongo 2.8's API, not PyMongo 3's. So Motor still does insert, update, remove, not the new insert_one, insert_many, replace_one, update_one, update_many, remove_one, remove_many.

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis Thank you for those expert informations !